# How can I wake a thread in macOS in a way that is async-signal-safe?

Tags: multithreading, macos, signals, thread-synchronization

I have a GRPC server application I'm developing on macOS. In this application, I need to handle SIGINT and SIGTERM in order to terminate gracefully.

Normally, on Linux, I would use POSIX semaphores, as the functions involved to wait and notify using a POSIX semaphore are async-signal-safe.

However, in macOS, POSIX sempahores are not implemented. I've looked at other possible synchronization primitives to use and I've stumbled upon `os_unfair_lock`, which looks nice, but in the documentation it does not state that it is async-signal-safe.

How can I safely have a thread waiting on a condition variable be woken up from a signal handler without resorting to polling an atomic variable, which would be burning CPU?

Thanks

EDIT: The application is in C/C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resorted to use `pipe()`.

1. Open the pipe before registering the signal handler

```cpp
  int fds[2];
  if(pipe(fds) != 0) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Unable to open pipe: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  struct sigaction newAction;
  newAction.sa_handler = signalHandler;
  sigemptyset(&newAction.sa_mask);
  newAction.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &newAction, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &newAction, NULL);
```

2. From the thread that needs to be waken up, we can just call `read()` with blocking IO to not waste CPU cycles. Bear in mind the call can return if interrupted by a signal, hence why we check for `EINTR`:

```cpp
ssize_t bytes_read = read(pipeFD, &msg, 4);
if(bytes_read == -1) {
  if(errno != EINTR) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Error reading from pipe: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    exitFlag = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

3. From the signal handler, we can `write` to the pipe. The `write` syscall is async-signal-safe:

```cpp
void signalHandler(int signal) {
  write(pipeFD, "EXIT", 4);
}
```

That does the trick. The user can validate the data sent by the pipe or not, according to `pipe(2)`, when both file descriptors are closed any remaining data is discarded.